# the meaning of the notation behind derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In Calculus, we are taught $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (first derivative), $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ (second derivative), ..., $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ ($n$-th derivative) respectively. Am wondering does the notion of a $\frac{d^my}{dx^n}$ ($m\neq n$) exist? what does that mean? any approachable, understandable reference you can cite for me (a non-mathematician, math hobbyist at best) to learn these concepts clearly from basic principles? Thank you.

Comment: The specific case of $m=1, n=0$ is called a [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) and it is often used, but is meaning is different for many authors. I think a good answer to this question should cover this. Also look at [higher order differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Higher-order_differentials) for any $m$ and $n=0$.

Comment: That particular notation is a compact way of writing ${d\over dx}{d\over dx}\cdots{d\over dx}y = \left({d\over dx}\right)^ny$. In it, ${d\over dx}$ is an indivisible symbol that means “derivative w/r to $x$” (the usual way of presenting separation of variables for differential equations notwithstanding).

Answer (score -1):

The notation is reminiscent of that for differences. The thing is that the first difference of a function $\Delta f=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$ is typically of the same order of $\Delta x$ (it is so at points where $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\neq 0$. If you consider the second difference $\Delta^2f=\Delta f(x+\Delta x)-\Delta f(x)$ (a difference of differences) it is a smaller infinitesimal, typically of the order of $\Delta x^2$, etc. This is why the interesting limits are the limits of $\Delta f/\Delta x$, $\Delta^2f/\Delta x^2$, etc. which are precisely the corresponding derivatives. If you divide $\Delta^2f/\Delta x^3$ you get infinity in the limit, if you divide $\Delta^2f/\Delta x$ you get zero because the infinitesimals have different orders. This is why $d^nf/dx^m$ with $n\neq m$ is not an interesting object, unless.. at a critical point you have $f'(x)=0$ and $\Delta f$ happens to be typically quadratic. Then, it makes sense to look at $\lim \Delta f/\Delta x^2$ which is equal to $f''(x)/2$ (just do Taylor expansion).  At certain singular points such mixed objects are finite and make perfect sense.

Nowadays they teach you that $df/dx$ is just a symbol and not a fraction. This is really sad, since the connection to differences is lost, not to mention the intuition behind the concept. There are fashions in Math like in anything. $df/dx$ is not a fraction now, but it was a fraction for the Mathematicians who created all the fundamentals of infinitesimal calculus in the XVIII and XIX centuries.

Comment: What about a differential? $df$, with whatever definition you use is arguably $\frac{d^mf}{dx^n}$, with $m=1, n=0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My comment was about such symbols when they represent (finite) quantities, not infinitesimals.

Comment: differentials are also often defined without infinitesimals (altough I don't like that, it is still sound). They are often defined in a point as $df := f'(x)dx$, where the left hand side is a linear function of $dx$ (just a variable) and constant in $x$.

Comment: Sure. You can define them as (multilinear) forms on the "tangent space". I like the classical point of view.

Comment: I like the classical point of view as well, but even then the notion of a differential makes sense as something non zero (i.e. an infinitesimal, formalized as for example an hyperreal). I strongly disagree that this is not an interesting object.

Comment: I can't agree more. They are just out of fashion. The algebraization of Calculus and Analysis has gone too far, in my opinion. The "fluid" nature of the subject has been lost, favoring finite quantities, epsilons and deltas and symbolic interpretations of infinitesimal quotients, etc. On the other hand, the "non-standard Analysis" point of view seems to me too complicated, not very intuitive if you really want to understand it. Promising, but ineffective.